# Chemical potential and gauge dependence in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, chemical-potential

A finite chemical potential contributes to the Lagrangian $\mathscr{L}$ of a QFT by coupling to the associated conserved charge $\mathscr{Q}$,
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L} \rightarrow \mathscr{L} -\mu \mathscr{Q}
\end{align}
Consider the  chemical potential associated to particle number, and say a scalar field $\phi$, at zero temperature. We then have a Lagrangian which looks something like
\begin{align}
 \mathscr{L} =|(i\partial_t - \mu)\phi|^2 - |\nabla\phi|^2 + ...
\end{align}

Bizarrely, it appears that one can eliminate the chemical potential through a time--dependent gauge transformation, ie $ \phi \rightarrow e^{-i\mu t}\phi$, after which $\mu$ does not appear in the Lagrangian. Relatedly, when one uses this theory to calculate various quantities, for instance through Feynman diagrams, when integrating over frequencies one will find that the dependence on $\mu$ can be eliminated by a change of variables.

If a chemical potential can be gauged away, how can it be physically meaningful (as it must)?

There is probably some subtlety related to the convergence of the path integral (and related quantities) -- $i\varepsilon $s and so on -- but it is not obvious to me for scalars.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of finite temperature QFT there will emerge some difference. Consider the grand canonical partition function:
$$
Z = \text{Tr} \ e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)}
$$
Where $H$ is the Hamiltonian, and $\mu, N$ are the chemical potential and particle number, correspondingly. The Green's function, defined as :
$$
G_{\beta, \mu} (t, x, y) = Z^{-1} \text{Tr} (\ e^{-\beta (H - \mu N)} O(t, x) O(0, y) )
$$
Now satisfies following boundary conditions:
$$
G_{\beta, \mu} (t, x, y) = e^{\mu \beta} G_{\beta, \mu} (t + i \beta, x, y) 
$$
Instead of being simply periodic in the imaginary time direction, they are now periodic up to the additional factor. One can trade off such "twisted" identification by making the aforementioned gauge transformation with parameter $-i \mu \tau$. By this procedure one trades of this identification for the introduction of background gauge field:
$$
A = \mu dt = - i \mu d \tau
$$

Comment: I agree that there is an obvious difference at finite temperature, but my question is about scalars at zero temperature. A finite chemical potential at zero temperature should still be physically meaningful.